how to add a link to dropdown buttons
Currently I am working on a django project and I am trying to add a dropdown menu on home page to change password and Log out.I tried to add links to dropdown menu buttons but it didnt work . I used bootstrap to style the page. The dropdown menu can be open and the buttons are seen but when I click on them it just didnt work I tried to put a href links instead of buttons but when I did that , I encounter with navbar alignment problems and also the dropdown menu didtn even opened so can you help about fixing the problem I dont have much information about js so I am really not sure my onclick usage in the buttons is right. Here is my html code.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body >
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<nav class="navbar-custom">
  <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="{% url 'home'%}">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1495088043/vector/user-profile-icon-avatar-or-person-icon-profile-picture-portrait-symbol-default-portrait.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=dhV2p1JwmloBTOaGAtaA3AW1KSnjsdMt7-U_3EZElZ0=" width="35" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top mr-4" alt="">
**      <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="custom-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-expanded="false">
              {{request.user.username}}
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'user_logout' %}';">Log out</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'password_change_view' %}';">Change password</button>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>**
          <button type="button" class="btn-close ms-auto" aria-label="Close" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'home' %}';">
          </button>
  </a>
</nav>
{% endif %}
<div class="vstack gap-2 col-md-5">
        <div class="sticky-xl-top">
        <figure class="text-center">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <h1 class="display-3">Yearbook System</h1>
            </blockquote>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'send_note' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success"> Send Note</a>
    <a href="{% url 'receive_notes' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success"> View Notes Written For You</a>
    <a href="{% url 'user_notes' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success">Your Notes</a>
    <a href="{% url 'password_change_view' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success"> Change Password</a>

</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/zO4TN2r5.png now it looks like this but when I add a href instead of buttons it looks like this
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/MwBEgRpB.png the navbar is out of the alignment and the dropdown menu doesnt open when I click on it

can you add two pictures: 1) what your code currently does 2) what you would like your code to do?

What does the rendered html look like?

actually all I want to do is adding a link to dropdown menu buttons . I added the photos . Hope you can help
